# ASP.NET (macOS) - Send Windows Credentials in SQL Connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm a contractor working remotely on a legacy ASP.NET application. I'm struggling to stand up a local instance of the project due to the error `SQL Exception - SQL Server does not exist or access denied`. I suspect this is because of the use of Windows Authentication for the SQL databases backing the project.

Before I launch into a lot more detail I'll ask my question: **what are my options to pass Windows credentials to an SQL server in an ASP.NET project built on OSX?**

I believe I've proven this is *possible* with some steps I'll detail below, but the actual implementation in an ASP.NET project is escaping me due to my inexperience with everything .NET, and the many-fold differences between my setup and the typical dev.

#### Standard Dev Setup

The devs I'm working alongside are using Windows machines housed in their corporate domain, running Visual Studio 2012. Because they're already logged into their machines with the appropriate credentials, the use of `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the SQL connection string "just works".

#### My Setup

I'm running a Mac Mini outside of their corporate domain, and using Visual Studio in conjunction with Mono to support the .NET Framework-based project. Passing the SSPI option won't work out of the box because I'm not connected to any Active Directory. That said, I do have valid credentials to log into their network.

#### What's worked so far

I've proven that a connection to their network resources is possible:

1. When logged into a virtual Windows machine, I can connect to a shared drive on that network with the credentials I was provided.
2. I then set up that same shared drive on my Mac Mini with those same credentials.
3. Using [SQL Pro for MSSQL](https://www.macsqlclient.com/), I was able to connect to the desired database using my credentials.

As I understand it, what I'm looking for can be accomplished on Windows with Credential Manager, so bottom line I think I'm looking for the equivalent solution on OSX that plays nicely with ASP.NET project as compiled by Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm confused.  You can only develop ASP.NET Core applications on Visual Studio for Mac, Visual Studio 2012 For Windows does not support developing ASP.NET Core applications and can only develop full framework (4.5) applications, so there is no way you can work on the same code base between each other.  So I don't understand how you're working on a legacy application with Visual Studio for Mac, it's not supported.

Comment: As I understand it, Visual Studio for Mac is backwards compatible with ASP.NET applications? FWIW, I'm targeting .NET 4.5

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  You cannot develop ASP.NET applications on Visual Studio for Mac.  Only .net Core applications.  See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-mac

Comment: You would be better off running Windows under Parallels or booting Windows via Bootcamp, assuming your Mini has the resources to do so.

Comment: In the case of complete non-compatibility, is this one of the ways it would present itself? Or would it manifest before runtime (compilation errors, unrecognized build files, etc.)?

Comment: Actually, before I abandon this completely I should also mention that I'm building this project in Visual Studio with Mono, which as I understand is mostly a replacement for .NET Framework on Mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156955/discussion-between-chris-and-erik-funkenbusch).